# Date column Error while importing excel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am reading a simple excel file into my code . excel has 2 column : inputDate[Date] and OutputDate[Date] ..

[image]

After importing Excel ; 2nd Column value is not coming properly ..it is coming like 42005 ,42006 instead of date .. **2nd column also include holidays , which I Needed as output**

[image]

here is my code

```
var fileName = string.Format("D:\\HolidayMaster", Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty));

var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data    
    source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", fileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From     
      [Sheet1$] ", connectionString);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From [Sheet1$]",connectionString);  

DataSet dsExcel = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dsExcel, "HolidayMaster");
```

This is the issue only for 2nd column ..What I am missing ?If this is not the proper way . what is the right way to get holidays and date as well

Comment: It is probably confused about the "date" you have in B5.

Comment: Have you tried configuring columns of the DataTable in DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET chooses data type based on the majority of the values in the column. That's why it is converting your 2nd column. In your case, B5 confuses ADO.NET

Try this (code not tested):

Change this line:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data    
source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", fileName);
```

To:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';", fileName);
```

Comment: Nops... still same response

Comment: see my edit, can you try that one?, and try to run your program while the excel is close. Try also to run the program if excel is open, see if you get the same result.